# What is the best way to take a partition of a dask dataframe and convert it to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

What is the best way to take a partition of a dask dataframe and convert it to a pandas dataframe? The following code seems to hang forever.

```
partitions = auc_ddf.to_delayed()
df = partitions[0]
df.head().compute()
```

Comment: try: `df = partitions.compute()`

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
auc_ddf.partitions[i].compute()
```

where `i` is the number of the part you want. Note that these parts are already pandas dataframes, so if your purpose is to process them in some way, then you probably don't need to do this at all.